# Apache Different AuthType in Nested Paths

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have a website running Apache/2.4.6 using `mod_auth_form`. However, I need to support basic auth on specific paths to support legacy applications.

With the configuration below, the site will always default to forms auth and will not prompt for basic auth on /legacy.

```
<Location "/">
    AuthType form
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    ...
</Location>

<Location "/legacy">
    AuthType basic
    AuthBasicProvider dbm
    ...
</Location>
```

Is there a way to configure the site to prompt for basic auth only in that directory without doing something like this?

```
<Location "/forms">
    AuthType form
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    ...
</Location>

<Location "/legacy">
    AuthType basic
    AuthBasicProvider dbm
    ...
</Location>
```

The option above would require changes to the current website, and I would like to have auth required at the root.